# why does this NSLog code print zero's for the values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string-formatting, nslog

Why does this objective-c code print 0's for the values, where as in debugger I can see they have non-0 values:

*Code*

```
CGRect currFrame = label.frame;                 
currFrame.origin.y = currVertPos;
currFrame.origin.x = 0;
currFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
currFrame.size.width = maxWidt  h;
NSLog(@"  currFrame dimensions:x/y/height/width = %d / %d / %d / %d", 0, currVertPos, expectedLabelSize.height, maxWidth);
```

*What is Printed*

```
currFrame dimensions:x/y/height/width = 0 / 0 / 0 / 0
```

Comment: The answers below are correct, but in addition you should have a look at the method NSStringFromRect() to help with easier printing of CGRect's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `%d` hence formatting the number as integers. Try using `%f` or `%lf` instead:

```
NSLog(@"  currFrame dimensions:x/y/height/width = %f / %f / %f / %f", 0, currVertPos, expectedLabelSize.height, maxWidth);
```

Comment: thanks - is there no formatter character you can use that would intelligently work out how to best format it based on type?  i.e. make it a little simpler

Comment: oh - I just tried with %f and it didn't work - got the following line as output "currFrame dimensions:x/y/height/width = 0.000000 / 0.000000 / 0.000000 / 0.000000"

Comment: Have you considered that the values might actually be 0?  Have you confirmed that they aren't?

Comment: oh - I've changed the 1st parameter passed in from "0" to a "0.0" and this seems to have fixed things - would be good if there was a generic formatting character you could use that would work for anything, e.g. int or float etc

Answer (score 6):

All these values have `CGFloat` type but you're trying to print them as `int`s. Just replace `%d` with `%f`.

P.S. Apple devs have to print `CGRect`s occasionally so they came up with some handy methods. Try `NSLog(@"currFrame dimensions: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(currFrame))`.